# OutPut of Map Reduce

Tags: mapreduce

Final output of Map Reducer is the combination of individual Reducers output.

For example if we have 3 reducers giving different output. Then final output of Map Reduce would be the combination of all 3 reducers output.
Is that True ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question, I would take an example of a MapReduce algorithm used to compute / estimate the numerical value of PI.

Assume there is a circle inscribed inside a square of 1 unit.

A map/reduce program estimates the value of pi using a quasi-Monte Carlo method.

The task between the **Mapper** and **Reducer** is defined as below:

Mapper:

1. Generate points in a unit square.
2. Count the points inside / outside of the inscribed circle of the square.

Reducer:

1. Accumulate points inside / outside results from the mapper.

Since the side of square is 1 unit, the area of the circle and the area of the square would be PI / 4 units (using area = PI * r * r) and 1 units (using area = a * a) respectively.

Let numTotal = numInside (number of points inside the circle) + numOutside (number of points outside the circle).

(Area of the circle) / (Area of the square) = numInside / numTotal (Since the circle is inscribed inside the square).

Therefore, numInside / numTotal = PI / 4

Hence, the value of PI = 4 * numInside / numTotal

Since many reducers may be responsible for accumulating the points inside / outside resulting from the mappers, their work is **additive** and hence the output is a combination of all the reducers involved.

Another example to this would be the word count in each file. I'd suggest you explore more about this from [here](http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.ca/2011/04/word-count-hadoop-map-reduce-example.html) and [here](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount).